# How to Sum with multitable

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(qty)
FROM table1
WHERE colum1 LIKE (
    SELECT colum2
    FROM table2
    WHERE condition2 LIKE 'value2'
)
```

Comment: This will only work if the subquery returns exactly one row.

Comment: You're better off using a JOIN.

Comment: I saw a lot of complicated JOIN explanations, is there s simple explanation for JOIN?

Comment: Does `colum2` really contain a `LIKE` pattern? Or is it just an ordinary string?

Comment: can you post a [mre] i don't see what you are trying and how your structure is

Answer (score 0):

It will work if the subquery returns a single row. When you use a subquery as an express, it must return a single value.

A more general method is to use a `JOIN`. This will sum the quantities of rows that match any of the selected `colum2` values.

```
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, qty
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.colum1 LIKE table2.colum2
    WHERE table2.condition2 LIKE 'value2'
) x
```

You need the subquery with `DISTINCT` in case `colum1` matches multiple patterns, so you don't sum the same quantity twice repeatedly for each match.

If `value2` or `table2.colum2` contains fixed strings rather than wildcard patterns, you should use `=` rather than `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work using

```
select Sum(column) from 
Table1 where column IN 
( Select column from TableName where 
Condition);
```